# Are shell functions exported to subprocesses, or not?

Tags: bash

According to man bash, shell functions are only exported to subprocesses if they are explicitly exported by using export or declare -x. Also, parentheses and backticks (including $(...)) run in subprocesses. So then why does this work?

```
    #!/bin/bash
    function x { echo x; }
    x
    (x)
    echo `x`
    echo $(x)
    bash -c x
```

I would expect to see "x" followed by 4 errors. In fact, I see 4 exes, followed by one error. How is this explained?

Comment: It is explained in [the manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Command-Execution-Environment).

Comment: builtin or shell function doesn't run a subpocess if you didn't force that  like "bash -c 'x'"

Comment: Right, so I would expect "x" (a shell function) to not run in a subprocess, and I would expect the next 3 lines (which are not builtins or shell functions) to run in subprocesses. But they do not! That is the question (answered below).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to axiac for posting the manual link. Usually I've found what I need in the man page, but here it's a little deeper. So I learned:

1. There is a thing called a "shell environment", which extends the usual process environment (environment variables, open files, etc) with defined functions (among other things, like shell variables).
2. Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses (and asynchronous commands) inherit a copy of the whole shell environment, except for traps.

The manual is a little confusing, as it also uses the phrases "execution environment" and "subshell environment" to refer to the same thing as the shell environment, but they all seem to refer to the same concept.

Thanks everyone!

Answer (score 2):

The bash man page states

> When a simple command **other than a builtin or shell function is to be executed, it is invoked in a separate execution 
>   environment** that consists of the following.
>
> ...
>
> - shell variables and functions marked for export, along with variables exported for the command, passed in the environment

and also

> **Command substitution, commands grouped with parentheses, and asynchronous commands are invoked in a subshell
>   environment that is a duplicate of the shell environment**, except that traps caught by the shell are reset to
>   the values that the shell inherited from its parent at invocation. Builtin commands that are invoked as part
>   of a pipeline are also executed in a subshell environment. Changes made to the subshell environment cannot
>   affect the shell's execution environment.

<sup>(emphasis mine)</sup>

Only the last command `bash -c x` is executed in a separate execution environment.

Comment: This is still confusing, as it isn't clear to me what a shell environment or a subshell environment is, or how they relate to an execution environment. Looking at the manual, it looks like they are all the same thing, as I summarised below. Also, you deleted the relevant part of the definition in this case, which is
° shell functions defined during execution or inherited from the shell’s parent in the environment
Cheers!